# Re-assign a variable in a function with computation expression

Tags: .net, haskell, f#, monads, computation-expression

Based on the question [How can I re-assign a variable in a function in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43525193/7821462), there is a haskell solution to change the total congo elephant count `Congo 0` in a `function`:

```hs
main' :: StateT Congo IO ()
main' =
  do
    printElephant
    function 2
    printElephant

-- run program:
main :: IO ()
main = Congo 0 & runStateT main' & void
-- outputs:
0
2
```

After reading the [Computation Expression series](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/), I still don't know how to write a CE builder for this problem correctly. How can I re-assign a variable in a function with F#'s CE?

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you're trying to do in much more detail. A fragment of Haskell code (missing critical pieces) doesn't seem to explain what you're trying to accomplish in F#.

Comment: F# isn't pure like Haskell and has mutable variables built-in. Or are you asking how to implement the state monad in F#?

Comment: @MiP - Since you've read the Computation Expression series and you're wanting to figure out how to implement the State monad, the next series you read should almost certainly be https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/handling-state.html, in which Scott Wlaschin explains that particular pattern with humor, his usual excellent diagrams, and a very fun metaphor.

Comment: @dfeuer you could see the code at the first link. Haskell seems so different comparing to F# so I don't fully know how to translate this code into F#.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# has a first-class support for imperative programming constructs. You just need to mark your let bindings as `mutable`. There is no need for computation expressions in this case:

```
let mutable elephant = 0
printfn "Elephant = %d" elephant
elephant <- 2
printfn "Elephant = %d" elephant
```

Comment: Although `mutable` can handle most of the use cases, my question is asking how to implement state monad in F# though.