# recursive function that prints something

Tags: haskell

I have a list of type `[Int]` which can only contain two values: `0` or `1`.

Example : `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`

I would like to iterate through this list and when the current element is a 0, print `'_'` and if it is a 1 print `'*'`.

For the previous list, here is the result on the standard output :

`__**__`

I think that I have to do something like that :

```
displayLine :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
displayLine (0 : xs) =
    do
        print '_'
        -- next char
displayLine (1 : xs) =
    do
        print '*'
        -- next char
```

How can I display a character and continue recursion with the next character?

Comment: You can just… call `displayLine` normally, can’t you? But a better way would be to write it in two parts: first write a function of type `[Int] -> String` to produce the string to print, and then `print` the resulting `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `displayLine` with the tail of the list. But here the type will be `IO ()`, not `IO [Int]` since the action does not return anything:

```
displayLine :: [Int] -> IO ()
displayLine (0 : xs) = do
        print '_'
        displayLine xs
displayLine (1 : xs) = do
        print '*'
        displayLine xs
```

You probably also want to use [**`putChar :: Char -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putChar) to print a single char, since `print` will call `show` and thus print a `Char` *literal*, and a new line.

This however duplicates logic. We can make use of [**`mapM_ :: (Foldable f, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> f a -> m ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_) to perform a mapping where each element performs a monadic action:

```
displayLine :: [Int] -> IO ()
displayLine = mapM_ (putChar . f)
    where f 0 = '_'
          f 1 = '*'
```

For example:

```
Prelude> displayLine [0,1,1,0,1,0] >> putStrLn ""
_**_*_
```

The `putStrLn ""` at the end is used to start a new line after the characters have been printed.

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about `do`-notation is that the code usually looks just like it would in an imperative language ([only better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622524/why-is-haskell-sometimes-referred-to-as-best-imperative-language)) : a couple of statements and a `return` at the end:

```
displayLine (0 : xs) =  do
    print '_'
    ys <- displayLine xs -- ys will be identical to xs,
    return (0:ys)
```

Don't forget to add a case for `displayLine []`, unless all of your lists are infinite....

BTW, do you really need to `return` anything, as the list is returned unchanged? If not, the type of `displayLine` could be `[Int] -> IO ()` and the definition could be even simpler..